# Plotting colored (heat) circular segments with R's 'shape' package (or some other package?)

Tags: r

I have a need to create an azimuth/distance color coded plot like the follow code which uses the 'shape' package.

---

```
library(shape)
emptyplot(xlim=c(-5,10), main="color segment test case")

filledcircle(r1=1, r2=2, from=0, to=pi/6, col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"),    numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.0,.0))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=1, r2=2, from=pi/6, to=2*pi/6, col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"),   numcol = 100), 
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.1,.1))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=1, r2=2, from=2*pi/6, to=3*pi/6, col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.2,.2))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=1, r2=2, from=3*pi/6, to=4*pi/6, col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100), 
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.3,.3))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=1, r2=2, from=4*pi/6, to=5*pi/6, col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100), 
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.4,.4))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=1, r2=2, from=5*pi/6, to=6*pi/6, col=intpalette(c("blue",   "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.5,.5))), zlim=c(0,1),  mid=c(0.0,0.0))

filledcircle(r1=2, r2=3, from=0, to=pi/6,col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.6,.6))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=2, r2=3, from=pi/6, to=2*pi/6,col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.7,.7))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=2, r2=3, from=2*pi/6, to=3*pi/6,col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.8,.8))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=2, r2=3, from=3*pi/6, to=4*pi/6,col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.9,.9))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=2, r2=3, from=4*pi/6, to=5*pi/6,col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.99,.99))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))
filledcircle(r1=2, r2=3, from=5*pi/6, to=6*pi/6,col=intpalette(c("blue", "yellow","red"), numcol = 100),
val=(cbind(c(0,1),c(.8,.8))), zlim=c(0,1), mid=c(0.0,0.0))

segments(0,0,3,0)
segments(0,0,2.6,1.5)
segments(0,0,1.5,2.6)
segments(0,0,0,3)
segments(0,0,-1.5,2.6)
segments(0,0,-2.6,1.5)
segments(0,0,-3,0)

plotcircle(r=1, from=0, to=pi, lwd=1)
plotcircle(r=2, from=0, to=pi, lwd=1)
plotcircle(r=3, from=0, to=pi, lwd=1)
```

---

The real world example of this plot would require some ten or more radii and likely would require the other half  of the plot, and maybe even a finer azimuth angle range. That will require dozens and dozens more line of code.

This plot is similar to a wind-rose plot, and various R packages (climatol for one) does something similar, but nothing exactly like this plot. I've looked in CircStats, circular, NeatMap, ggplot2, and climatol, and nothing there seems to fit the bill.

Does anyone know of another R package that can create this kind of plot by just feeding it a dataframe or a matrix of numbers and a color palette definition?

Answer (score 5):

This type of plot is certainly possible using `ggplot2`.  Quoting from the help page for `coord_polar`:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(movies)
movies$rrating <- cut_interval(movies$rating, length = 1) 
movies$budgetq <- cut_number(movies$budget, 4)
doh <- ggplot(movies, aes(x = rrating, fill = budgetq))
doh + geom_bar(width = 0.9, position = "fill") + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: Andrie, I saw a reference to polar coordinates on page 136 and 137 of Hadley's ggplot2 book, but the example displays on page 137 didn't give your example as a possibility so I didn't look any further. I'll have to look further. Thanks.